# How can I query a TFS Build Definition custom defined variable within a PowerShell Build Step

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

In my TFS Build Definition I want to create a custom variable within the Variables Tab. This variable I want to name `MyVariable`.

In my Build Definition I have a PowerShell script step.
In this powershell script (PS1) I want to query the value of the variable.

How can I do this?

The following things I tried, but these do not work:

```
Write-Host "MyVariable: $Env:MyVariable"
Write-Host "MyVariable: $MyVariable
```

Comment: You don't provide your ps1 code. You mix double `"` with `)` and so on... Your question needs to be edited to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manu is right, the PowerShell script format is incorrect.

Please try:

```
Write-Host "MyVariable:" $Env:MyVariable
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works without passing the Variable as arguement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the variable into your Powershell script task using the Arguments section. If your variable is named MyVariable then it should be passed in the following format: $(MyVariable)
In your Powershell script, you can access the value of the variable since you are passing it as an argument.

Comment: If I add `-MyVariable "$(MyVariable)"` to the powershell arguemnts then it works. Thanks. But Andys solution it the one actually I was looking for.